# Python over-indentation warning E127

Tags: indentation, elpy

`elpy` (or rather `flake8` I suppose) complains about a line over-indented on the line 52 (see below image)

[image]

I tried to change this line's begin but no change.
I always use TAB to have the correct indentation (and this position is where TAB leads).

Here's my `elpy` config:

```
Emacs.............: 26.3
Elpy..............: 1.33.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: python3 3.8.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/david/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: /usr/bin/python3 3.8.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: 0.17.0
 Rope.............: 0.17.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.2
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: 19.10b0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/david/.local/bin/flake8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create in your home folder a `.flake8rc` file, and add some content to ignore that error - [documented here](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html) and below is a small template:

```
[flake8]
# it's not a bug that we aren't using all of hacking
ignore =
    # F812: list comprehension redefines ...
    F812,
    # H101: Use TODO(NAME)
    H101,
    # H202: assertRaises Exception too broad
    H202,
    # E127: continuation line over-indented for visual indent
    E127
```

The full error code listing is [here](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes)

Comment: that works, great! BTW, flake8 rc file is on my system `~/.config/flake8`